# Is there some way to override a function of superclass either from extension functions or from interfaces in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

In android to do some tasks we require the user to grant related permissions. Complete process of checking and requesting permission involves 3 steps: checking permission, requesting permission and checking result. If the permission is denied, then don't need to run that task. So to simplify this, I wrote the following interface and extension function in ActivityExtensions.kt

```
private val permissionTaskSource = HashMap<Int, TaskCompletionSource<Boolean>>()

interface PermissionHandler {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    fun Activity.permissionRequest(requestCode: Int, vararg permissions: String): Task<Boolean> {
        requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode)
        val tcs = TaskCompletionSource<Boolean>()
        permissionTaskSource[requestCode] = tcs
        return tcs.task
    }

    fun permissionResult(requestCode: Int, grantResults: IntArray) {
        permissionTaskSource[requestCode]!!.setResult(grantResults.all { it == PERMISSION_GRANTED })
        permissionTaskSource.remove(requestCode)
    }
}

suspend fun <T> T.requiresPermission(vararg permissions: String): Unit? where T : Activity, T : PermissionHandler {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        return Unit   // If version lower than M then no need of runtime permissions.
    if (permissions.all { ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, it) == PERMISSION_GRANTED })
        return Unit   // If already all permissions granted, then no need to ask again.

    val granted = permissionRequest(System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), *permissions).await()
    if (granted)
        return Unit   // Permission granted now
    return null   // Permission denied now
}
```

Whenever required some permissions to do a task in an activity or fragment, I can use this line:

```
private suspend fun someTask() {
    requiresPermission(/* list of required permissions */) ?: run{ /*permission denied. handle properly*/ return }
    // Inside fragment this has to be called with requiresActivity() receiver.
    ...
}
```

This whole thing is working fine.. but in every activity/fragment I have to write these 4 lines of code.

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    permissionResult(requestCode, grantResults)
}
```

Is there some way I can move these codes also to `ActivityExtensions.kt` file to make it much neater and avoid repetitive code?

Comment: It's not the answer, but now it's more comfortable to work with permissions with Android Results API (it's good written about it here: https://wajahatkarim.com/2020/05/activity-results-api-onactivityresult/).

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii Nyc resource.. I will go through it.. Thanks :)

Comment: I prefer to repeat this code in each activity and avoid the inheritance... but with inheritance only needs to do this in a BaseActivity and extends this class in each Activity.

Comment: @ManuelMato may I know why you prefer to repeat the code over inheritance? (other than replacing `Activity` with `MyActivity` everywhere looks ugly.)

Comment: Because a few activities (1,23?) will be to check the location permission so a BaseActivity is dangerous because in the future maybe grow the functionality with another behaviors, so i prefer an extension function

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB did you find a way to do what you wanted?